# How can I return "Access Denied" for object in GraphQL (API Platform) item query when using security in a Query Extension

Tags: graphql, api-platform.com

I am using the `QueryItemExtensionInterface` (with API Platform, GraphQL) to prevent a user from viewing objects they do NOT have access to. In a Query Collection the items are removed from the result as expected, but when querying for a specific object (`item_query`) the result is an object with a value of `NULL`.

I would prefer that I get an 'Access Denied' response instead of a null data value (As I do when using `security` api-platform attributes). Is there a way I can configure my entity to act this way when the security is being enforced in a Query Extension (implementing `applyToItem()`)?

Comment: explore the rest of network response - https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Errors

Comment: Thanks, yes the `errors` array is empty, and is where I'm hoping to see the 'Access Denied' message.

Comment: query extension affects query, not "validate" the result ...  I'd try `itemOperations={"get" = { "security_post_denormalize"`  -  if null

Comment: Great, this does the trick!
```
'item_query' => [
          'security' => "is_granted('ROLE_USER')",
          'security_post_denormalize' => 'object != null'
        ],
```

Comment: @xadm, happy to give you the opportunity to answer officially. Otherwise, I am happy to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query extension affects query creation (sql), it's not for result "validation".

You can use resolver stages - https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/#workflow-of-the-resolvers - e.g.

```
'item_query' => [ 
   'security' => "is_granted('ROLE_USER')",
   'security_post_denormalize' => 'object != null' 
],
```